# Constraining slope

Tags: regression, stata

I'm a beginner in Stata. I'm trying to run the following regression:

`regress logy logI logh logL`

but I would like to constrain the slope of `logh` to be one. Can someone tell me the command for this?

Comment: Elsewhere on our site--I cannot find the place now--it has been pointed out that what you want is equivalent to regressing `logy - logh` against the remaining variables `logl` and `logL`.

Comment: I just found out the constraint is: 
**constraint 1 logh = 1**

where **constraint** is the code, 1 is the constraint number, **logh** is the variable, and **=1** is to set the parameter equals to 1. 

It's also possible to set sum of slopes on logI and logh equal to one using
**constraint 2 logI+logh=1**

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/683-constraining-slope-in-regression Statalist etiquette is clear: you are asked to be explicit about cross-posting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the correct code in Stata. As it has already been answered here and on Statalist, referring it to SO is pointless.

Comment: I also had flagged this question for the same reason but was declined for whatever the reason. Hard to see how this is not about Stata code only though.

Comment: The interpretation resisting closure is the statistical content, but what the OP doesn't know statistically is not spelled out and the emphasis is entirely on the command needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least three ways to do this in Stata.

1) Use constrained linear regression:

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. constraint 1 mpg = 1

. cnsreg price mpg weight, constraints(1)

Constrained linear regression                     Number of obs   =         74
                                                  Root MSE        =  2502.5449

 ( 1)  mpg = 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |          1  (constrained)
      weight |   2.050071   .3768697     5.44   0.000     1.298795    2.801347
       _cons |  -46.14764   1174.541    -0.04   0.969    -2387.551    2295.256
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

2) Variable transformation (suggested by whuber in the comment above):

```
. gen price2 = price - mpg

. reg price2 weight 

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  1,    72) =   29.59
       Model |   185318670     1   185318670           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |   450916627    72  6262730.93           R-squared     =  0.2913
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.2814
       Total |   636235297    73  8715552.01           Root MSE      =  2502.5

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      price2 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |   2.050071   .3768697     5.44   0.000     1.298795    2.801347
       _cons |  -46.14764   1174.541    -0.04   0.969    -2387.551    2295.256
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

3) Using a GLM model with an offset:

```
. glm price weight , family(gaussian) link(identity) offset(mpg)

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -683.04238  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -683.04238  

Generalized linear models                          No. of obs      =        74
Optimization     : ML                              Residual df     =        72
                                                   Scale parameter =   6262731
Deviance         =  450916626.9                    (1/df) Deviance =   6262731
Pearson          =  450916626.9                    (1/df) Pearson  =   6262731

Variance function: V(u) = 1                        [Gaussian]
Link function    : g(u) = u                        [Identity]

                                                   AIC             =  18.51466
Log likelihood   = -683.0423847                    BIC             =  4.51e+08

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |                 OIM
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |   2.050071   .3768697     5.44   0.000      1.31142    2.788722
       _cons |  -46.14764   1174.541    -0.04   0.969    -2348.205    2255.909
         mpg |          1  (offset)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The glm route could also handle the log transformation of your outcome for you if you change the link and family options appropriately.